# Modal with Changing Content

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am making a modal in a file named modal.html and the content that is to populate the modal is from an external JS file. The content is the string returned by the following function in a JS file named one.js:

```
function current()
{
  if(selection === 0 && yesResources[questionsCounter] != null)
  {
    return yesResources[questionsCounter];
  }
  else if(selection === 1 && noResources[questionsCounter] != null)
  {
  return noResources[questionsCounter];
  }
  else
  {
    return 'You are on the right track!';
  }
}
```

The HTML code written for the modal is as follows:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <h2>Resources</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p id='modalContent'></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Living Progress</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to call the current() function to populate the paragraph space with id 'modalContent'. I've tried using document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = current(), document.getElementById("modalContent").textContent = current(), calling the function between the paragraph tags, etc. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the id name when you typed document.getElementById(), and I suggest you use document.querySelector('#modalContent'), because this way it can also be applied to selecting the classname or tagname.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `document.getElementById("modalContent").textContent = current();` instead of `document.getElementById.textContent = current()` (you forgot to point `id` after `getElementById`).

Comment: I did include it but made a mistake in the above post, so I fixed it there. The modal completely stops appearing when I do as you said, do you know why this might be? Remember the current() function is coming from an external JS file

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = "Your content here";
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: David, I used that, with the difference that the text on the right side of the equals sign is replaced with current() in my case. It seemed to make the modal stop displaying completely... Do you have any idea as to why?

Comment: Probably the yesResources or the noResources are returning something different than a string, can you provide us with this content so we can think throw it?

Comment: yesResources and noResources contains elements that are either strings or null. Is it because of the null elements?

Comment: It's not because of the null. I did some trouble shooting and the function I am calling is not defined, meaning the HTML file does not recognize the function. Why is this?

Comment: The one.js is imported in your project? It would be like this <script src="/js/one.js"></script> But you should place the correct directory for your js file

Comment: The rest of the program works and it's all coming from one.js, so I am not sure why the page says the function is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I checked your javascript code, the style is not good, and condition is too long. And I modified the code as below.

```js
var e = function(sel) {
    return document.querySelector(sel)
}

function current() {
    var yR = yesResources[questionsCounter]
    var nR = noResources[questionsCounter]

    if (selection === 0 && yR != null) {
        return yR;
    } else if (selection === 1 && nR != null) {
        return nR
    } else {
        return 'You are on the right track!'
    }
}

e('#modalContent').innerHTML = '<h1>hi is here</h1>'
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. The modal does not appear at all when I try this.

Comment: nevermind, the modal still works but the data from the current() function is not being put inside the modal